# parse error on number column google sheets when copied from google docs

Tags: google-sheets

I copied table into sheets, but shows parse error with value function when trying to convert into number format for modifying column data further.

is there a way out, also what kind of format it copies from google doc to sheets that it gives parse error?

Comment: https://easyupload.io/uypi07 , pls enlighten

Comment: number, so that I can add values to each row

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below formula:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. but y didn't value alone worked since it says it can accept text?